# What does navigator.javaenabled() means when javascript is the language(base) supported by browser?

Tags: javascript, navigator

I was just checking navigator object and saw the `javaEnabled()` method. so why it's there and what is use of java when javascript is only language interpreted by browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [the specification](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/system-state.html):

> The navigator.javaEnabled() method must return true if the user agent supports **a plugin** that supports the MIME type "application/x-java-vm"; otherwise it must return false.

(My emphasis).

It is for determining if there is support for, for example, Java Applets (which require a plugin). In 2019 there usually isn't, but it was common two decades ago.

Comment: So it's related to java plugins?

Answer (score 1):

This method indicates whether the current browser is Java Run Time Environment-enabled or not.

> The return value for this method indicates whether the preference that controls Java is on or off - not whether the browser offers Java support in general.

This method does NOT determine if javascript or active scripting is enabled in the web browser or not. To detect if active scripting is enabled in a web browser add  tags to your web page.

**Example**

Feature test for Java JRE. Negative results do not mean that Java JRE is not installed on the client. It can also indicate that the Java JRE has been disabled by the client Addons Manager or the Java JRE control panel.

```
if (window.navigator.javaEnabled()) {
      // browser has java JRE and it is enabled.
}
```